# Copying data from PC to MacBook Pro

Tags: switching, file-transfer

I am going to purchase a 15.4" Macbook Pro by this month. I have a Windows laptop at this moment. Can I transfer my data from from a NTFS formatted disk on my PC to a Mac?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, files can be transferred from a NTFS drive to a Mac.  Apple provides [documentation](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2518) on the process. This is a relatively straightforward process.

The bigger challenge is not reading files from a different disk operating system, but rather proprietary formats used by particular programs. Common formats like jpeg, html, etc. will pose no problem, and programs like Microsoft Office or Adobe Photoshop are available on both platforms. Files from Microsoft Publisher, however, or other more obscure Windows programs can be *ported* to the Mac, but you may find yourself without a program on the Mac that can read or edit those particular files.

Comment: For those file formats which are not supported by MAC, I can use parallels and install windows?But as you said things like  songs and videos wont give any issue.

Comment: Mac* jeeze stop all capsing. and gl find file formats you can't use on a mac other than .exe, .ini and .bat (windows executable files)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the migration assistant check out [support.apple.com/kb/HT4796](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4796) don't start the computer until you read the article especialy the subsection "Click here if the Mac is starting up for the first time and Mac OS X Setup Assistant appears"

It seems that the transfer can be made over the network so no NTFS problems ;)